# I want to upgrade my laptop's RAM. Windows reports MaxCapacity as 32GB but the manual say 16GB. Which is it and why?

Tags: memory

My laptop is a HP 14-ck0521sa. The supplied RAM is 1 x 4GB DDR4-2400 SODIMM and there's 1 additional slot.
I'd like to install 2 x 16GB.

I'm wondering if the manufacture quotes a lower figure in the hope that users would be encouraged to buy higher spec'd (read priced) laptops. Or is there a genuine physical limitation, such as power consumption, dimensions, or heat dispersal.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your laptop's memory limit is 16 GB. [HP's website for that specific model](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-laptop-14z-fq000-9vn16av-1?jumpid=cs_con_nc_ns&utm_medium=cs&utm_source=ga&utm_campaign=HP-Store_US_BRA_PS_CPS_Hgm_AMD_Google_DO_PLA&utm_content=sp&adid=504252209944&addisttype=gpla&9VN16AV_1&cq_src=google_ads&cq_cmp=12495445162&cq_con=114111274970&cq_term=&cq_med=pla&cq_plac=&cq_net=g&cq_pos=&cq_plt=gp&gclid=CjwKCAjw1uiEBhBzEiwAO9B_HSzUHA094LPRQvj5gc0kAdLkONcMWIesU9l7URGGLB-JiWvVOwWUXxoCAesQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) lists under the specifications tab memory configurations up to 16 GB.

Additionally, entering the model information to [Crucial.com's memory selector page](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/hp---compaq/hp-14-ck0521sa) provides the same limitations.

Comment: Yup, I got all that, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I know from years ago that laptops sometimes support more RAM than cited in the spec, and that the spec sometimes seems to cite what is the maximum available at date of release. I think in this case only experience can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

With DDR4, the limit of ram memory should be higher than 16GB. I would say 32GB should be compatible. The only reason why 32GB should not be compatible is because the length of the address is exacly 34 bits long (what kind of number is that?) and you need 35+ bits for 32GB. Since your CPU supports addresses of 64 bits, you should be ok.